# Android app, Google maps api location validation for java

Tags: java, android, api, validation, google-maps

I'm using Android Studio to create an app that utilizes google maps api. I am having trouble validating if the user input is an actual location.

i.e if the user enters "fdfdfaef", program crashes.

i have the following code to store the user "location" input:

```
address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1)
```

Any help on how to check if the input is valid or not or at least to prevent a crash. Thanks and appreciate it.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question a little more??

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code, I will go out on a limb and suggest that you might be doing this on your main UI thread.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29),

> The query will block and returned values will be obtained by means of
>   a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed
>   to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from
>   a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

Try doing a async task that requests information using the Geocoding API. On getting a result, update the UI. Offloading to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) will prevent the crash, at the very least.

Does that help you?